# Reading data from USB host every 200ms in android app

Tags: android

My USB Host is receiving sensor data and it is getting updated every 200ms. I would like to read this data in my android app every 200ms. I am able to read it using bufferreader, It reads the data for sometime and then hangs. It is not consistent. I am new to this and may be I am not doing it the correct way. Below please find my code and let me know your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

```
public void startProcessOne()
{     
    new CountDownTimer(110,100)
    {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();        
            line = "";
            try {

                FileReader in = new FileReader("/mnt/udisk/TEST.TXT");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);        
                int i=0;
                char[] buf = new char[10000];
                while((i = br.read(buf,i,100))!= -1)
                {
                    String h = new String(buf);
                    text.append(h);
                    text.append('\n');
                }

                br.close();

            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                //You'll need to add proper error handling here        
            }

            TxtRead.setText(text.toString());      
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish()
        {               
            startProcessOne();
        }

    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Is it textual data that you read? No lines? Where does it hang? Why a buffer of 10000 where you use only 100? And if you read i then add i chars instead of the whole buf.

Answer (score 0):

> `TxtRead.setText(text.toString());`

This line is causing the problem. You can't touch UI elements from a background thread. You should instead run those codes in the UI/Main thread.

In your case, I'd personally prefer using Java threads. So, create a background thread to keep running periodically. If you would need to run UI methods from that background thread. You probably need a handler attached to the main thread.

```
// Instantiate a handler in UI thread
final Handler handler = new Handler();

new Thread(new Runnable(){
    // Once you're done and want to break the loop, just set this boolean
    private boolean stopped = false;

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(!stopped) {    
            // Read from the file

            // Whenever you need to update an UI element,
            // you should wrap it inside this runnable object
            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    // Update UI
                    TxtRead.setText("new_text");
                }

            })

            try {
                // This thread will sleep for 9 seconds
                Thread.Sleep(9000);
            } catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Hi Frogatto: Thanks for your response. I have tried following and still the same issue.

Comment: @user5644476 I'm pretty sure, it works just fine. Please double-check your other stuff.

Comment: I need to read every 200ms from file and update the textview. I updated Thread.sleep(9000) to Thread.sleep(200). It is reading as expected and after sometime it hangs. I am no sure why it is stopping after sometime. I need to read continuously from the file and update the results in textview. Are there any other options available to read the data from USB every 200ms?

Comment: @user5644476 What do you mean by "it hangs"? Do you mean exception? If so, please show me the logcat.

Comment: I don't see any error message in logcat. After further investigation it looks like it is related to caching. My USB hub is receiving sensor data every 500ms and it looks like it is either caching the data or the text file is not being updated. If you have any suggestions to fix this then please let me know. Thanks